# error Error: read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20 error in nodemailer

Tags: mern, nodemailer

I am trying to send email using "nodemailer"  but every time I got this error

[image]

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

router.post("/sendmail", async (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "gmail",
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL,
            pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
        },
    });
    const mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL,
        to: email,
        subject: "Sending Email For password Reset",
        html: "<h1>Congratulation You successfully send Email</h1>",
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("error", error);
        } else {
            console.log("Email sent", info.response);
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Email sent Succsfully",
            });
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

this is my code can anyone help me to solve this problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after some research I find out this:

> Gmail has a limit of 500 recipients a day (a message with one To and
> one Cc address counts as two messages since it has two recipients) for
> @gmail.com addresses and 2000 for Google Apps customers, larger SMTP
> providers usually offer about 200-300 recipients a day for free.

If you exceed the quota, this error will appear. If you wait until the next day, the problem will be solved.

One way around this is to create another email and alternate the senders between messages.

https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/